# ListView - Center Cell Views Horizontally w/o ListView Height Wrap_Content

Tags: android, performance, listview, gravity

I am currently having some formatting issues with Android's ListView. After looking through several questions on SO I did not find any proper solutions.

I have a ListView (used for navigation) including one or more views (actual navigation items). What I want to achieve is - the ListView uses up the whole vertical space (heigth set to match_parent) and the cells are centered vertically in this ListView.

[image: This should be the result]

Simply setting the gravity to center_vertical for the ListView does not do the trick. I currently can only achieve this look if I wrap the ListView in another view (which has set the gravity to center_vertical) and change the ListView's height to wrap_content. But this seems not to be the perfect solution as the resulting measuring operations (the adapter’s getView method is called multiple times for the same position) have a performance impact, even if applying a proper holder concept for the navigation items. Is there any solution to this issue?

ListView (gravity does not work):

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/lvNavigation"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navWidth"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />
```

ListView with workaround (bad performance):

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="@dimen/navWidth"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <ListView android:id="@+id/lvNavigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Navigation item:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/horizontalMargin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/horizontalMargin">

    ...

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Post your list as well as list item layout.

Comment: I have added the relevant layout parts.

Comment: If it is bad performance use Relative layout and give centerVertical=true to listview.

Comment: remove the android:gravity="center_vertical" in the <ListView /> xml declaration.    <ListView android:id="@+id/lvNavigation"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navWidth"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/> is enough

Comment: @Harry: I tried your solution, but `getView` is still called multiple times due to measuring reasons (ListView's height is set to wrap_content).

Comment: @VishnuPrabhu Actually this does not achieve the look I am looking to achieve.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood, did you try using android:layout_weight=1 and android:layout_height="0dp" for the list_item_root_container. I mean adding those values to the LinearLayout in the NavigationItem.xml

Answer (score 1):

Listview is probably a bad thing to use for this purpose. I think what you should do is use a recycler view with a custom [Layout Manager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager.html)

In particular you probably want to override [onLayoutChildren](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager.html#onLayoutChildren(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.Recycler,%20android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.State))

I did a quick search and could not find a library that does this for you already.

Alternatively, if you have elements where you can predict the height you can [add a header view](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView(android.view.View)) that is blank and set the height so that the list items will appear centered.

So something like

```
ListView lv = getListView();
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
ViewGroup header = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.header, lv, false);
header.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(<width>, <height>));
lv.addHeaderView(header, null, false);
```

Comment: I will take a look into the RecyclerView.